# The POM for ... is missing, no dependency information available, even though I have the dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm trying to build a JAR file using Maven. It depends on NASA WorldWind, which was suspended. I have the JAR files required, but I still get the same error.

I tried going to Project > Clean in the Eclipse IDE, but that did not work either.

```
[WARNING] The POM for gov.nasa:gdal:jar:latest is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for gov.nasa:gluegen-rt:jar:latest is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for gov.nasa:jogl-all:jar:latest is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for gov.nasa:worldwind:jar:latest is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for gov.nasa:worldwindx:jar:latest is missing, no dependency information available

[...]

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project chunkmapper: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.chunkmapper:chunkmapper:jar:0.2: The following artifacts could not be resolved: gov.nasa:gdal:jar:latest, gov.nasa:gluegen-rt:jar:latest, gov.nasa:jogl-all:jar:latest, gov.nasa:worldwind:jar:latest, gov.nasa:worldwindx:jar:latest: Failure to find gov.nasa:gdal:jar:latest in http://eclipse-repo.appspot.com/repo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of eclipse-repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

[pom.xml](https://hastebin.com/ucagomasox.xml)

Comment: Please add the `pom.xml` to your question.

Comment: @JFMeier Okay done

Comment: Please include the text into the question.

Comment: I actually figured it out. I went to the Maven Repository and got what I needed. Thanks anyway.